# How do I overcome developer anxiety as a Web Developer?

Tags: career-development, productivity

Graduated with a Degree in Information Technology and have been building websites using wordpress for 2 years but somehow feel that doesn't make me an actual web developer and that I feel left behind. I'm good with HTML and CSS but struggle with understanding Javascript and any other Programming Languages and just to depend on stackoverflow for help copying and pasting code. I kinda envy the younger people that seem to do more. I'm 26 years old by the way and have been learning to build websites using wordpress on my own

Comment: I'm not sure you qualify as a web developer either. Are you seeking to apply for web development positions? Or just think you're being overpaid?

Comment: I'm actually a web developer right now for a digital agency. What I'm trying to say is how can I raise my confidence as a web developer

Comment: Do your best to learn more and not let the impression you have of others fool you?

Comment: If you want to gain confidence with JavaScript, how about reading a book on JavaScript? Eventually you can be the one answering questions on StackOverflow rather than seeking the answers.

Comment: the younger people?  You're 26!  You are the younger people!

Comment: Very related on Academia: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect

Comment: I was just about to post an answer before this question got closed - so I [dumped it on pastebin instead](http://pastebin.com/zbRN4AW3). Good luck.

Comment: sounds like you're a Wordpress developer rather than a web developer per se.

Answer (score 3):

If programming languages are difficult for you then maybe that is not the best path for you. But if that is what you want then practice.  Get a text book on Javascript and do all exercises.  Read a general book on object oriented programming (OOP).

Answer (score 2):

There is generally three types of developers in the world, decide which category you fall into and plan accordingly.

1. You love programming, and do it all the time for fun. I expect a large number of people who use StackOverflow or similar programming help websites are probably in this category. I do not believe this is you.
2. You are doing it because you enjoy it, or something about it. I find most people are in this category. Its easy for them but they are disinterested, or perhaps just love the environment at work.
3. You just look at it as a job.

If you think you of it as just a job, and are not willing to spend much additional time in it then maybe it is time to swap careers or at least re-evaluate. If you really want to get better at it - stop using wordpress or similar stuff. Next time you have a problem break it down into the parts you can solve and do them. Try making a website from scratch with no copied code, write everything yourself. When you finish you will probably notice a vast improvement in your understanding. Don't feel bad if its not as nice as the fine-polished WP sites either, you have to build up and get better.

In the world of coding, practice makes perfect. Also don't get down on yourself, most of this community is slightly older then you with years more experience.

Comment: yeah  it gives me a sense that is need to man it up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are two(or more) directions you can go to as a web developer. 
1) you can become better at coding, php, javascript, ajax, SQL, etc. going straight into OOP as Frisbee suggested may be a bit too intimidating at first. but that wouldn't be a bad step after knowing the basic coding.
2) Improve at designing. This would mean things like photoshop, illustrator, etc. Making your websites looks better than other websites.

Nearly every occupation out there has ways to develop into other jobs. Employees can become project leaders and eventually managers. You yourself could start as a web developer into a web software engineer, or web designer.

You may be really good at what you do, and that has a value in it's own. However I'd always recommend anyone to keep developing themselves.